# Searching for Playlists with search.list in youtube api doesn't work properly

Tags: c#-4.0, youtube, youtube-api, youtube-data-api, playlist

I'm making a youtube uploader and I wanted to include a feature that would allow you to upload a video and simultaneously add it to a playlist on the uploader's channel, but i hit a roadblock - If i use this code to search for playlists on the channel

```
SearchResource.ListRequest searchresource = youtubeService.Search.List("id, snippet");
        searchresource.Type = "playlist";
        searchresource.Q = richTextBox11.Text;
        searchresource.MaxResults = 50;
        searchresource.ChannelId = channelId;
        SearchListResponse searchresponse = searchresource.Execute();
```

It seems to only search for playlists containing videos with titles containing the text I'm searching for, which in turn causes small playlists with only one or two videos to not come up.

Examples:

Big playlist with 50 videos that comes up
[image]

Small playlist with only one video that doesn't come up:
[image]

Comment: What's your desired result? How isn't it working properly?

Comment: @noogui it doesn't find the playlist called "playlist test"